# find series of number in C linux using regular expression

Tags: c, regex

I used the code below that uses the "{}" but seems its not working as expected when using C.

```
int basic_regx(char *format, char *name)
{
     regex_t     regex;
     char        array[100];
     if( regcomp(&regex, format, 0) )
         return; 
     if( !regexec(&regex, name, 0, NULL, 0) )
         printf ("Succeeded\n");
     else 
         printf ("Not Succeeded\n");
     regfree(&regex);    
 }
```

If I call function with follwoing:

```
Success - basic_regx("^[0-9]$","0");
Not Success -- basic_regx("^[0-9]{1,4}$","0");
Success - basic_regx("^[0-9]{1,4}$","0{1,4}");
```

Thats mean the {} is not taken as expected by the reg implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regcomp` and `regexec` use POSIX regular expressions; in other words, it only supports features described in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). If you want Perl-style regular expressions, which support this expression, you may need an external library such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

However, with POSIX regular expressions, you can do the equivalent:

```
basic_regx("^[0-9]\\{1,4\\}$","0");
```